# How to update an Associative Array

Tags: php

I do not know what is wrong with my php code.  I want to have an Associative Array in the format.  When I run my code I get this data.  [KY] is an array in the [OH] array.

```
Array ( [Oh] => Array ( [state] => Oh ) [income] => 100 [count] => 1 [Ky] => Array ( [state] => Ky ) )

Array (
   [OH] => Array 
   ( [income] =>
     [count] =>
   )
   [KY] => Array
   ( [income] =>
     [count] =>
   )   

Here is my code
Example data in $array
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[SurveyDate] => 1952-06-21 
[Income] => 100 
[CountyState] => Hamilton|Oh 
[count] => 1 ) )

function update_array_value3( $array )
{
    foreach ($array as $row) 
    {
        $arrCountyState = explode( "|", $row['CountyState'] );

        $key = $arrCountyState[1];  // OH or KY

        if( !isset( $_SESSION['sIncome'][$key] ) )
        {
            $_SESSION['sIncome'][$key]['state'] = $key;
            $_SESSION['sIncome'][$key]['income'] = $row['Income'];
            $_SESSION['sIncome'][$key]['count'] = 1;
        } else
        {
            $_SESSION['sIncome'][$key]['state'] = $key;
            $_SESSION['sIncome'][$key]['income'] += $row['Income'];
            $_SESSION['sIncome'][$key]['count'] += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: first off, there is no reason to pass `$array` by reference as you are not modifying the value of it. 

Turn: `update_array_value3(&$array)`

to: `update_array_value3($array)`

The same applies to your `foreach()` loop, you do not need to be passing `$row` by reference (remove the `&`).

Comment: Can you update the question to show us the structure of `$array`, can't really help you until we know what we are working with.

Comment: Removing the & from $array and $row fixed the issue.  I have no idea why but I am extremely happy.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you the root cause of the problem simply based on this snippet of code, but it seems `$row` either doesn't contain the data you expect it to, or doesn't contain any data.

In your code you reference `$row['CountyState']`, yet I don't see any array item called `CountyState` in `$array`.

Also, I'm not sure whether or not this is intentional, but in your `foreach()` loop it looks like `$_SESSION['sIncome']['income']` and `$_SESSION['sIncome']['count']` are being overwritten. Each time the loop encounters a new `$key`, it will overwrite those values.